# Zend_Db subquery

Tags: php, zend-framework, subquery, zend-db, zend-db-table

I've been trying to construct a sql query with ZendFW, but I cant seem to get it to function like I want to (or function at all). This is the query that works that I'm trying to build with zend_db select()

```
SELECT tc.trip_title, td.ID, td.trip_id, 
  (SELECT count(*) FROM 'trips_invites' ti 
   WHERE ti.destination_id=td.ID AND ti.accepted ='NR') AS "pending_invites" 
FROM `trips_current` AS `tc`, `trips_data` AS `td` 
WHERE (tc.ID=td.trip_id) AND (tc.creator_id = '1') 
ORDER BY `trip_id` ASC
```

What I can't figure out is how to properly get that subquery in there, and nothing I try seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

**Edit/Answer:** If anyone will ever have a similar problem, based on the suggestion below I re-worked by query in the following way:

```
SELECT `tc`.`trip_title`, `td`.`ID`, `td`.`trip_id`, count(TI.ID)
FROM `trips_current` AS `tc` 
INNER JOIN `trips_data` AS `td` ON td.trip_id = tc.ID 
LEFT JOIN trips_invites AS TI ON ti.destination_id = td.id
WHERE tc.creator_id = 1  AND ti.accepted='NR'
GROUP BY td.id
ORDER BY `trip_id` ASC
```

which using ZendFW I created this way:

```
$select = $this->dblink->select() 
->from(array('tc' => 'trips_current'),
      array('trip_title'))
->join(array('td' => 'trips_data'), 
'td.trip_id = tc.id',                   
      array('ID','trip_id'))
->joinLeft(array('ti'=>'trips_invites'),
     'ti.destination_id = td.id',
     array('COUNT(ti.id)'))
->where('tc.creator_id =?',1)
->group('td.id')
->order('trip_id');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, you can do this with `GROUP BY`:

```
$select = $db->select()
  ->from(array("tc"=>"trips_current"), array("trip_title"))
  ->join(array("td"=>"trips_data"), "td.trip_id = tc.ID", array("ID", "trip_id"))
  ->joinLeft(array("ti"=>"trips_invites"), "ti.destination_id = td.ID", array("COUNT(*)")
  ->where("tc.creator_id = ?", 1)
  ->group(array("tc.ID", "td.ID"))
  ->order("trip_id");
```

I'm assuming you're using MySQL.  The group-by is simpler that way because of MySQL's permissive nonstandard behavior.

**edit:** I change the above query to use `joinLeft()` for ti.  This is in case no invites exist for a given destination, as you mention in your comment.

---

If you really need to use a subquery, you can create it separately and then interpolate it into the select-list of your main query:

```
$subquery = $db->select()
  ->from(array("ti"=>"trips_invites", "COUNT(*)")
  ->where("ti.destination_id = td.ID");

$select = $db->select()
  ->from(array("tc"=>"trips_current"), array("trip_title", "($subquery)"))
  ->join(array("td"=>"trips_data"), "td.trip_id = tc.ID", array("ID", "trip_id"))
  ->where("tc.creator_id = ?", 1)
  ->order("trip_id");
```

Zend_Db_Select knows to look for parentheses in the column named in your select-list and skip delimiting such columns.

Also I would like to point out that you don't have to use Zend_Db_Select just because it's there.  That class is best for when you need to build up a query with parts that depend on variables or application logic.  If you know the full SQL query and it doesn't depend on application conditions, it's more clear to just write it out in a string -- just like you wrote out in your original question.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, and I am using MySQL, but unfortunately that doesn't produce the result I'm looking for. I should mention that not every td.ID has an associated ti.destination_id, and I think thats why I'm better of using a subquery. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you very much! I still had a problem with the subquery as it seemed to generate the right query but got delimitinated wrong by the Zend_Db_Select (even when I tried using the Zend_Db_Expr). So I gave up on that. But thanks to your suggestion, I reworked my query to use a leftjoin/groupby to avoid the need for the subquery. Thank you very much! 
I still have other parts of the query that depend on application logic which is why I wanted to use zend_db_select to begin with.

Comment: this worked perfect for me . here" `array("trip_title", "($subquery)"))` i added `array("trip_title", "($subquery) as subquery"))` so that ill see the result only

Comment: what is $db ? How to get it ?

Comment: @PratikCJoshi, it's an instance of the Zend_Db_Adapter class. Please read the documentation, it tells you how to create one and some basic information on how to use it: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html