# How execute query with subqueries in zend framework

Tags: sql, mysql, zend-framework

Hi I need write this sql with Zend_Db_Select, but I dont know how I can write subqueries. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
SELECT * FROM advert WHERE categoryId
           IN (
             SELECT id
              FROM `tree`
              WHERE `lft` BETWEEN 
               (SELECT lft FROM tree WHERE id = '2') AND 
               (SELECT rgt FROM tree WHERE id = '2'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// create the main query
$select = new Zend_Db_Select();

//create the subquery
$subSelect = new Zend_Db_Select();

// using the subquery in main query
$select->where('table.field IN(?)', $subSelect->assemble());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221285/zend-db-subquery) will help you decide between using `standard sql queries` and `zf-made ones`.

I myself don't recommend using Zend_Db_Select for complex and scarcely used queries.