# Normal MYSQL QUERY to ZEND QUERY

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I Want to write this normal mysql query to zendquery

```
SELECT *,(select GROUP_CONCAT(keyword_name,',') 
   from keyword k inner join keyword_product_mapping m 
       where k.keyword_id=m.keyword_id and m.product_id=p.product_id) 
           FROM product p
```

Comment: Did you make any attempts to solve it that you could share?

Comment: Exactly i dont know how to write sub query in zend. The normal query is a working one.

Comment: First write the subquery in Zend, then write the main query (without specifying the subquery) in Zend. Post that here and we'll be able to help you with patching them together ;-).

Comment: Maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922246/how-execute-query-with-subqueries-in-zend-framework